# loop or code for user wrong input until correct input c++

Tags: c++, calculator

I am new to c++, and I was assigned to create a calculator and ask for the user input and calculate the numbers. I also have to create a code for when the user inputs the wrong number, the program will ask the user to input the right number. How do I create a code for when the user enters the wrong input, it repeats the whole code again.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int UI() {
  int choice;
  cout << "Enter the correspendonce number for the following options you want "
          ": \n1.Addition\n2.Subtraction\n3.Multiplication\n4.Division\n\n "
          "Option: ";
  cin >> choice;
  return choice;
}

int add(int a, int b) {
  int c = a + b;
  return c;
}

int subtract(int a, int b) {
  int c = a - b;
  return c;
}

int multiply(int a, int b) {
  int c = a * b;
  return c;
}

int divide(int a, int b) {
  int c = a / b;
  return c;
}

// main function
int main() {
  int total;
  int num1, num2;
  int choice;

  choice = UI();

  if (choice == 1) {
    cout << "Input two numbers you wish to calculate for :";
    cin >> num1;
    cin >> num2;
    total = add(num1, num2);
    cout << " the total is " << total << "\n";
  } else if (choice == 2) {
    cout << "Input two numbers you wish to calculate for :";
    cin >> num1;
    cin >> num2;
    total = subtract(num1, num2);
    cout << " the total is " << total << "\n";
  } else if (choice == 3) {
    cout << "Input two numbers you wish to calculate for :";
    cin >> num1;
    cin >> num2;
    total = multiply(num1, num2);
    cout << " the total is " << total << "\n";
  } else if (choice == 4) {
    cout << "Input two numbers you wish to calculate for :";
    cin >> num1;
    cin >> num2;
    total = divide(num1, num2);
    cout << " the total is " << total << "\n";
  } else {
    cout << "Entered wrong input, please select option 1 - 5";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple approach is to set a flag:

```
bool done = false;
while (!done)
{
    done = true;
    int choice = UI();

    if (choice == 1) {
    
        // etc ...

    } else {
        cout << "Entered wrong input, please select option 1 - 4\n";
        done = false;
    }
}
```

Another option is to offload that logic into your input function:

```
// Gets 1-based choice up to count.  Returns 0 on error.
int GetChoice(int count)
{
    while (cin >> choice)
    {
        if (choice >= 1 && choice <= count) {
            return choice;
        }
        cout << "Invalid choice.  Enter value from 1 to " << count << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then you can simply call:

```
int choice = GetChoice(4);
```

The problem with this is you'll get an error if the user enters `hello` or any non-integer.  The simplest way to get around this using line-based input:

```
// Note, you also need to include <string> and <sstream>

int GetChoice(int count)
{
    string input;
    while (getline(cin, input))
    {
        int choice;
        istringstream iss(input);
        if (input >> choice) {
            if (choice >= 1 && choice <= count) {
                return choice;
            }
        }
        cout << "Invalid choice.  Enter value from 1 to " << count << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

These are some practical solutions.  You could engineer something fancier if you wish.

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped, and my code is running smoothly !

Answer (score 0):

You can use goto as basic, so when the user enters any number other than 1, 2, 3 or 4, she will ask her to enter a number again.But remember, the use of goto is not recommended in good coding practice.It offers a simple solution to your simple problem.

```
 int UI() {
            int choice;
        x:   
            cout << "Enter the correspendonce number for the following options you want "
                ": \n1.Addition\n2.Subtraction\n3.Multiplication\n4.Division\n\n "
                "Option: ";
           
            cin >> choice;
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
                return choice;
            default:
                cout << "Please enter 1&2&3 or 4\n";
                goto x;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Come on, it's not 1989...  Using `goto` for this problem is reprehensible advice.

Comment: @paddy I absolutely agree with you that using goto is bad and I stated this in replying.If we look at the question, the friend asking the question is very basic. my goal was to provide him with a simple solution without creating a syntax crowd and making it difficult to understand.Otherwise it is not good to use goto of course.

Comment: You're welcome to justify it that way, but bear in mind you already introduced new syntax by using switch AND recommended a solution that is not common practice at all.  Much like the "simple solution" for someone getting in your face is to kill them instead of negotiate.  It might be a solution, but it is by no means the norm, and is only the beginning of more problems.

Comment: @paddy Thank you for sharing your valuable experiences.From now on I will consider what you said while helping people.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with the below code.
Easy solution is that you wrap the code which you want to repeat in while loop
and the loop will only end when the user enters correct input otherwise loop will repeat, to end the loop use "break".

```
int main() {
  int total;
  int num1, num2;
  int choice;

while(1)
{
  choice = UI();

  if (choice == 1) {
    cout << "Input two numbers you wish to calculate for :";
    cin >> num1;
    cin >> num2;
    total = add(num1, num2);
    cout << " the total is " << total << "\n";
    break;
  } else if (choice == 2) {
    cout << "Input two numbers you wish to calculate for :";
    cin >> num1;
    cin >> num2;
    total = subtract(num1, num2);
    cout << " the total is " << total << "\n";
    break;
  } else if (choice == 3) {
    cout << "Input two numbers you wish to calculate for :";
    cin >> num1;
    cin >> num2;
    total = multiply(num1, num2);
    cout << " the total is " << total << "\n";
    break;
  } else if (choice == 4) {
    cout << "Input two numbers you wish to calculate for :";
    cin >> num1;
    cin >> num2;
    total = divide(num1, num2);
    cout << " the total is " << total << "\n";
    break;
  } else {
    cout << "Entered wrong input, please select option 1 - 5";
  }
}
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you change and why? A good answer should explain things and help people to understand the language better. Just providing code will lead to cargo-cult-programming.

Comment: @churill i understood what u r saying i edited my answer.

Comment: This introduces the potential for error, because of code-duplication -- any changes to the code must recognize that `break` is critical for preventing incorrect behavior (_e.g._ if adding new choices).  While it's simple in such a trivial example to identify and test this, it is something to keep in mind always, because one day you will be writing code in a vastly more complex environment, and it's beneficial to make the behavior as obvious as possible.